# Constraint handling, integer & parallel optimization

Tags: openmdao

I have recently been assigned to a project where an optimization tool will be developed in python.

Various online search points out there are multiple libraries/platforms that come with pros and cons. As far as I have looked up with the existing openmdao framework we can not have an optimizer that can do constraint handling, mixed-integer, parallel optimization. Here with parallel it is meant that each iteration should be parallellized as in GADriver. I wanted to ask some advice from the developers considering the future possible improvements on openmdao:

- Is it a good idea to look into writing a wrapper for an existing optimizer that can handle the aforementioned request or should one opt out from openmdao completely as openmdao may not be the strongest platform in this specific problem?
- if writing a wrapper is a good idea i assume one should look for driver routines in the openmdao 2.2.X github. Do you have any advice for an optimizer type within python (paid or free) that can be easily compatible with openmdao.

Comment: I suggest writing a context for your question. What kind of optimization? Website optimization? Data size optimization ?
Describe sample data sets if exists, example problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an AIAA paper titled ["Next generation aircraft design considering airline operations and economics"](http://openmdao.org/pubs/roy_amiego_2018.pdf), which described current state-of-the-art research into mixed integer programming problems. The approach here used a hybrid method that takes advantage of the efficient gradient based capabilities of OpenMDAO to handle larger numbers of continuous design variables.

In general, there is no limitation on mixed integer programming. You just need to write your own driver to handle it. These algorithsm are complex, but SimpleGADriver is a decent place to start to see how to run the model in parallel.

Comment: Thanks i will look at the paper in detail. Just a quick follow up 


1- In the paper it states AMIEGO is available in the openmdao as a driver is this a future reference?



2- Maybe a rookie question but i am running the simpleGADriver in parallel and timing the runs. It does not seem to scale. Do i understand correctly that turning the parallel option should distribute the generations to the cores. For the sample code in the manual I increased to max_gen=1000 and results 


time mpirun -n 2  python gadnew.py 

real 0m16.347s


time mpirun -n 1  python gadnew.py

Comment: user@userubuntu:~/Desktop$ time mpirun -n 2  python gadnew.py 
comp.f [0.49454471]
comp.f [0.49454471]

real 0m16.347s
user 0m31.039s
sys 0m0.352s
user@userubuntu:~/Desktop$ time mpirun -n 1  python gadnew.py 
comp.f [0.50279674]

real 0m10.379s
user 0m10.151s
sys 0m0.091s

Comment: This could be a bug. I will look into it.

Comment: Just to clarify, max_gen is analogous to the number of iterations that the GA performs. The "pop_size" argument is the number of points in your population, and those are what are distributed to the cores.

Comment: If I use a very quick model, then I see similar results to you, where the mpi overhead swamps any gains you get from splitting the population evals between two processors. If you try a model that is a little slower (like adding a 0.05 second sleep to the compute), then good scaling is shown:  [ 1proc: 13.06 sec vs 2proc: 6.65 sec].  I will add a benchmark to OpenMDAO that shows this.